# Como separa o valor de elementos de uma coluna por delimitador ("|" e " ") no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split

vamos imaginar que temos uma coluna com essas informações:

```
|Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |
|Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|
|Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|
|Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|
|Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|
```

Preciso fazer um Split que retire o delimitador ("|" e " ")

```
meu código:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('teste1.xlsx')

df[['Nome', 'Nome_meio', 'Sobrenome']] = df['|Nomes| Nome_meio|  Sobrenome|'].str.split('|' ,n=2,expand=True)

df1 = df.drop(columns=['|Nomes| Nome_meio|  Sobrenome|'],axis=1)

df1.to_excel('teste1.xlsx' ,index=False)
```

Output do meu código:

```
Coluna1   Coluna2    Coluna3
Nome      Nome_meio  Sobrenome
          Larissa       Manola    |Santos|
          Manoel        Rosa    |Toy|
          Ronaldo       Fenomeno    |Pereira| 
          Elon          Musk    |da Silva|
```

Output esperado:

```
Coluna1     Coluna2     Coluna3
Nomes       Nome_meio   Sobrenome
Larissa     Manoela     Santos
Manoel      Rosa        Toy
Ronaldo     Fenomeno    Pereira
Elon        Musk        da Silva
```

Comment: não esqueça de confirmar a resposta abaixo, se ela responde a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solução baseada no exemplo que você apresentou.

### Criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"coluna": ["|Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |","|Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|","|Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|","|Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|","|Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|"]})

df
                                      coluna
0  |Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |
1           |Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|
2                  |Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|
3         |Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|
4               |Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|
```

### Removendo primeiro e último delimitador

```
df["coluna"] = df["coluna"].str[1:-1]

df
                                    coluna
0  Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome
1           Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos
2                  Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy
3         Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira
4               Elon|    Musk    |da Silva
```

### Transformando string com delimitador (|) para lista

```
df["coluna"] = df["coluna"].str.split("|")

df
                                        coluna
0  [Nomes,     Nome_meio     ,     Sobrenome ]
1           [Larissa,     Manoela    , Santos]
2                  [Manoel,     Rosa    , Toy]
3         [Ronaldo,     Fenomeno    , Pereira]
4               [Elon,     Musk    , da Silva]
```

### Criando novo dataframe contendo apenas as colunas

```
novo_df = pd.DataFrame(df['coluna'].to_list(), columns = ['Nome', 'Nome_meio', 'Sobrenome'])

novo_df

      Nome           Nome_meio       Sobrenome
0    Nomes      Nome_meio           Sobrenome
1  Larissa         Manoela              Santos
2   Manoel            Rosa                 Toy
3  Ronaldo        Fenomeno             Pereira
4     Elon            Musk            da Silva
```

### Concatenando dataframes lado a lado

```
df = pd.concat([df, novo_df], axis=1)

df
                                        coluna     Nome           Nome_meio       Sobrenome
0  [Nomes,     Nome_meio     ,     Sobrenome ]    Nomes      Nome_meio           Sobrenome
1           [Larissa,     Manoela    , Santos]  Larissa         Manoela              Santos
2                  [Manoel,     Rosa    , Toy]   Manoel            Rosa                 Toy
3         [Ronaldo,     Fenomeno    , Pereira]  Ronaldo        Fenomeno             Pereira
4               [Elon,     Musk    , da Silva]     Elon            Musk            da Silva
```

### Limpando espaços à esquerda

```
df["Nome"] = df["Nome"].str.strip()
df["Nome_meio"] = df["Nome_meio"].str.strip()
df["Sobrenome"] = df["Sobrenome"].str.strip()

df
                                        coluna     Nome  Nome_meio  Sobrenome
0  [Nomes,     Nome_meio     ,     Sobrenome ]    Nomes  Nome_meio  Sobrenome
1           [Larissa,     Manoela    , Santos]  Larissa    Manoela     Santos
2                  [Manoel,     Rosa    , Toy]   Manoel       Rosa        Toy
3         [Ronaldo,     Fenomeno    , Pereira]  Ronaldo   Fenomeno    Pereira
4               [Elon,     Musk    , da Silva]     Elon       Musk   da Silva
```

### Apagando primeira linha

```
df = df.drop(df.index[0])

df

                                 coluna     Nome Nome_meio Sobrenome
1    [Larissa,     Manoela    , Santos]  Larissa   Manoela    Santos
2           [Manoel,     Rosa    , Toy]   Manoel      Rosa       Toy
3  [Ronaldo,     Fenomeno    , Pereira]  Ronaldo  Fenomeno   Pereira
4        [Elon,     Musk    , da Silva]     Elon      Musk  da Silva
```

**Nota**: É possível economizar passos `chaining` os comandos como por exemplo abaixo:

```
novo_df = pd.DataFrame(df['coluna'].str[1:-1].str.split("|").to_list(), columns = ['Nome', 'Nome_meio', 'Sobrenome'])
```

Comment: Vou usar os seu dados para apresentar uma resposta.

Comment: Maravilha, corrigiu os problemas com o delimitador. Ótima solução!

Answer (score 0):

Se nos nortearmos no conjunto hipotético de dados propostos na [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/550443/137387) e consolidados [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/550523/137387)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
 {"coluna": ["|Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |",
             "|Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|",
             "|Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|",
             "|Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|",
             "|Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|"
            ]
 }
)
```

Uma solução é gerar um novo DataFrame a partir dos dados da coluna em questão usando o método [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Seguindo os passos:

- Remova o primeiro e o último caractere `|` de cada linha da coluna usando o método [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) que retorna uma cópia da string com caracteres no início e no final removidos segundo o argumento passado ao método.
- Com o método [`pandas.Series.str.cat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) junte todas as linhas da coluna em uma string, configurando o separador de linhas para `sep="\n"`.
- A partir da string gerada anteriormente crie na memória um fluxo de texto com [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).
- Com o método [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) leia o fluxo de texto mudando o delimitador do padrão `,` para `|` a ser usado configurando parâmetro `sep="|"`

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"coluna": ["|Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |","|Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|","|Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|","|Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|","|Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|"]})

csv = df1["coluna"].str.strip("|").str.cat(sep="\n")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), sep="|")

print(df2.head())
#    Nomes     Nome_meio          Sobrenome 
#0  Larissa        Manoela             Santos
#1   Manoel           Rosa                Toy
#2  Ronaldo       Fenomeno            Pereira
#3     Elon           Musk           da Silva
```

Para remover os espaço dos dados das colunas ao ler um csv é possível utilizar o parâmetro `converters` de `pandas.read_csv()` que é um dicionário de funções para trabalhar valores em determinadas colunas. As chaves podem ser números inteiros ou rótulos de colunas. Especificamente usei `converters={1:str.strip}` pois no exemplo apenas a coluna `Nome_meio` apresenta os espaços, porém nada impede de aplicar uma mesma função a todoas ou mais de uma coluna `converters={0: str.strip ,1:str.strip 2: str.strip}`

Os rótulos das colunas também contém espaços que podem serem removidos com `str.strip()` assim `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()`

Exemplo completo:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"coluna": ["|Nomes|    Nome_meio     |    Sobrenome |","|Larissa|    Manoela    |Santos|","|Manoel|    Rosa    |Toy|","|Ronaldo|    Fenomeno    |Pereira|","|Elon|    Musk    |da Silva|"]})

csv = df1["coluna"].str.strip("|").str.cat(sep="\n")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), sep="|", converters={1:str.strip})

df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()

print(df2.head())

#     Nomes Nome_meio Sobrenome
#0  Larissa   Manoela    Santos
#1   Manoel      Rosa       Toy
#2  Ronaldo  Fenomeno   Pereira
#3     Elon      Musk  da Silva
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Replit](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/pipecsv#main.py)</sup>

Comment: boa solução usando o `str.cat()`. Porém, (i) não removeu os espaços, (ii) caso o `df` original possua mais colunas seria necessário fazer o concat (ou merge) de qualquer forma.

Comment: Exatamente como nosso amigo Paulo Marques mecionou foi uma boa solução. Pois removeu o delimitador "|" , porém não removeu os espaços. Podemos usar `replace()` para remover os espaços.

Comment: @ANDERSONHENRIQUELUIZ Fiz uma edição vejam se adequa suas necessidades.